# NSURLConnection sucking memory when profiled using leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, instruments

I am having a really hard time optimizing my app performance as it sucks too much memory.
Here's the allocation instruments call tree:

[image]

I am unsure my self why it's sucking 5 MB of the app it self.. the leaks instruments is not showing that I am leaking up any memory. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try setting the shared NSURLCache to something that is reasonable for your application.

See http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/ios-ipad-iphone-nsurlcache-uiwebview-memory-utilization/ for an example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
    int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"] autorelease];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

    // ... more launching code
}
```

Comment: is that diskPath basically just a string?

Comment: From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) path is the name of a subdirectory of the application’s default cache directory in which to store the on-disk cache (the subdirectory is created if it does not exist).

Comment: can you comment on the drawRect?

Comment: I think you mean drawTextInRect. That will be memory used to describe the font(s) you used.